Casimir eigenvalues of p-adic automorphic representations
In the context of p-adic local Langlands correspondence:
Is it possible to define Casimir eigenvalues for p-adic automorphic representations? If a local representation arises from a global Galois representation, are there specific expected eigenvalues, analogous to the situation in global Langlands for elliptic curves? References would be appreciated.

Q1: Sort of, but it depends what you mean by p-adic automorphic representation. "U_p eigenvalues" of overconvergent p-adic automorphic forms are roughly analogous, as are "infinitesimal characters" of locally analytic representations of p-adic groups.
Q2 (in any reasonable interpretation): Definitely not. The set of local Galois representations which are globalizable is a countably infinite and somewhat random-looking subset of the space of all local Galois representations (say with fixed residual representation, HT weights and inertial type).

1/2. Regarding A1: I was thinking of a more direct analogue. Perhaps using the definition of the Casimir as a set of generators for the center of the Lie algebra, and considering their induced Lie derivatives. On A2: I imagine that if we restrict to the set of isomorphism classes of reps coming from pure global reps with prescribed weight and ramification, this set is even finite. In a reasonable definition of a p-adic local Langlands correspondence, I would expect it to look like a restriction of the Global case.

2/2. For a global rank $2$ automorphic rep. of $\text{GL}2(\mathbb{A}{\mathbb{Q}}$, coming from a global Galois rep., we know the rep. should look like a discrete series, generated by the Maass $L$ and $R$ operators, on certain automorphic forms related to modular forms, both in terms of their Casimir eigenvalues, and their Fourier-Whittaker coefficients. This gives strong restrictions on their Fourier-Whittaker coefficients (contained within a finite dimensional vector space of expansions). I wonder if anything replaces Fourier-Whittaker coefficients in the local case, meaningfully.

My second answer to A1 was an extremely direct analogue, which makes me think you don't know the relevant definitions; btw, Casimir comes from center of the universal enveloping algebra, which is very different from the center of the Lie algebra itself.

Thanks for the correction, and the answers!

You're welcome, and my apologies for being salty. By the way, if you want to read about infinitesimal characters in the setting of Q1, you should look at this great paper: https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/gabriel.dospinescu/sen_weights_2020.pdf
